# Adptive Streaming in Gstreamer

Tags: video-streaming, gstreamer

How we can do adaptive streaming using gstreamer?
I have created client and Server app using gstreamer framework.I am able to do live video streaming . But, I would like to adaptive way depending on network condition the bitrate can be change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest way to do that is to encode and prepare content in multiple bit rates and resolutions on the server and let the client to switch between the content based on its available bandwidth. Most of the HTTP streaming systems follow this principle.

In the context of gstreamer on the server you need to set-up multiple pipelines to create multi-bitrate content or use a Tee to split video to different encoders from source.

I suggest you to go through microsoft silverlight smooth streaming or any of the adaptive HTTP streaming specifications to get more details.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But, how the client will switch between the contents based on the bandwidth? could you please explain me how the client will know about different content? Or Should I  predefined the bit rate in server and client???

Comment: In very simple terms HTTP adaptive streaming servers will have a playlist file (an xml file or any other format). This will have info about different bitrate streams. This in one example http://download.microsoft.com/download/4/2/4/4247C3AA-7105-4764-A8F9-321CB6C765EB/IIS_Smooth_Streaming_Technical_Overview.pdf
In simplest terms client can start with lowest bitrate and increase it if it finds it is able to download 1 sec video in say 0.2 sec unti l it finds it takes more than 1 sec to get a 1 sec chunk. This can go on.

Comment: This doesn't help if your video producer (e.g. video streaming uploader on mobile device) has limited bandwidth. Are there any alternatives?